# SQL Remove Substring From Query Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace, sql-server-2012

I have a query that is returning data from a database. In a single field there is a rather long text comment with a segment, which is clearly defined with marking tags like `!markerstart!` and `!markerend!`. I would like to have a query return with the string segment between the two markers removed (and the markers removed too).

I would normally do this client-side after I get the data back, however, the problem is that the query is an `INSERT` query that gets it's data from a `SELECT` statement. I don't want the text segment to be stored in the archival/reporting table (working with an OLTP application here), so I need to find a way to get the `SELECT` statement to return exactly what is to be inserted, which, in this case, means getting the `SELECT` statement to strip out the unwanted phrase instead of doing it in post-processing client-side.

My only thought is to use some convoluted combination of `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX`, and `CONCAT`, but I'm hoping there is a better way, but, based on [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx), I don't see how. Anyone have ideas?

Sample:

This is a long string of text in some field in a database that has a segment that needs to be removed. !markerstart! This is the segment that is to be removed. It's length is unknown and variable. !markerend! The part of this field that appears after the marker should remain.

Result:

This is a long string of text in some field in a database that has a segment that needs to be removed.  The part of this field that appears after the marker should remain.

SOLUTION USING STUFF:

I really don't like how verbose this is, but I can put it in a function if I really need to. It isn't ideal, but it is easier and faster than a CLR routine.

```
SELECT STUFF(CAST(Description AS varchar(MAX)), CHARINDEX('!markerstart!', Description), CHARINDEX('!markerend!', Description) + 11 - CHARINDEX('!markerstart!', Description), '') AS Description
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Why not `remove()` both `!markerstart!` and `!markerend!`?

Comment: I want to remove the markers and the text, which varies in length, between the two markers.

Comment: It would be better if you could show a sample text and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Stuff function or Replace function and replace your unwanted symbols with ''.
STUFF('EXP',START_POS,'NUMBER_OF_CHARS','REPLACE_EXP')

Comment: That's good, but it still means I have to find the start position and the length somehow.

Comment: no , you can use functions like charindex and left or right, to figure out positions.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider implementing a CLR user-defined function that returns the parsed data.

The following link demonstrates how to use a CLR UDF RegEx function for pattern matching and data extraction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Regards,